# Help identifying this SMD component (IR sensor)

Tags: pcb, sensor, identification, surface-mount, infrared

I have a mini differential IR sensor PCB that serves as the bed probe for my 3d printer.  Looking at the SMD components, there are a few items I can not find or identify.  Does anyone know the part numbers for the components outlined in red in the photo below?

---

Update:
The black item is definitely a sensor.  The two clear items are certainly emitters.  My question is around part numbers in case anyone recognizes them.  This is a custom part I purchased on aliexpress - not stock for my printer.  The device is fairly simple.  The two emitters produce an IR beam.  The black sensor detects the coincidence of the two beams when they bounce off an object at a fixed distance of about 2 mm.

[image: photo of populated PCB with some components highlighted in red]

Comment: Can you provide additional information, like to close up of the 3 SMD components. The make and model of the 3D Printer might help too. The information is limited  help respond.

Comment: The two white ones are IR LEDs and the black one is an IR sensor. If nothing is written on these components, then probably it's impossible to know the exact part number, unless you get help from the manufacturer.

Comment: I think the black sensor is of the 38 or 42 kHz de-modulator type.

Comment: Look at the output of the sensor to see if it's a digital output or analog, you'd really need to know what ouptut wavelength the LED's have to narrow it down. We could tell you the package type, what they are will be impossible without more info on the wavelength or smt markings.

Comment: @VoltageSpike he doesn't sound like a person who would have access to wavelength measuring equipment.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig "or smt markings"

Comment: The net output of this circuit is definitely digital.  It is meant to act as a trigger for sensing solid objects.  The sensor I gather is meant to produce a certain voltage when exposed to IR.  The digital output is produced when the IC logic is satisfied by a comparison of the emitter trigger frequency and the sensor voltage spike frequency.

Comment: Can you explain a little why do you want to identify the part numbers of the IR emitters and receiver? Do you have a faulty unit and want to replace it? Or do you want to write the part numbers in your project report? Or are you just curious?

Comment: Because if you get it from Aliexpress, most likely it would have built in an unidentifiable factory in China. And the objective of most of those factories is to give you the cheapest product with whatever components they find on that particular day, as long as it is working like expected.

Comment: You question is closed, if you explain the purpose, I might try to help you. Or may even edit the question appropriately to try it to get opened.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I've located the original design on github.  Turns out these are Osram parts.  The emitters are SFH4045N.  The IR sensor is SFH3015FA.

Answer (score 1):

The two white ones on the right are IR LEDs and the black one on the left is an IR sensor. For exact part numbers, you need to find something written on the devices, or get help from the manufacturer of this module.

Comment: You can confirm it by observing the LED using a mobile phone camera. It appears to emit a white light when it is turned on.

Comment: The LED is red and it triggers when the ATTiny25 IC code is satisfied.  The IR emitters trigger at a specific frequency.  When the sensor is tripped at that same frequency, the logic is satisfied and voltage is put through to the left most pin at the terminal block.

Comment: I get what you are saying. By "LED is red", you mean the small LED labeled D3?